# TeamViewer Connection Issue

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer, unattended

Lately I've been coming across an issue with TeamViewer, the issue is that the PC will show that it is online but it'll decline my connection multiple times until it finally gives up and gets me connected.

The PC in question is a renewed Dell OptiPlex 3020 PC that is running Windows 10 Pro and has been set up with TeamViewer unattended host. The PC is just out of the box and doesn't have many things installed.

Edit - The main issue I'm having is that I am receiving this error when trying to connect to a TeamViewer Host PC:
"No connection to partner!
Partner did not connect to router.
Error Code: WaitforConnectFailed"

But after attempting to connect 5 times, I'll finally get access to the Host PC. Is this a known issue with TeamViewer?

Comment: From which device are you connecting? I've had similar issues when connecting to some Windows host from an Android device and TeamViewer support suggested changing the Windows host TeamViewer settings unchecking "Use UDP (recommended)" which helped.

Comment: I'm using my main PC to connect to the device. My PC is a Dell OptiPlex 9020 running Windows 10 Pro. It also doesn't help that once I am able to connect to the Host PC, I'll be able to disconnect and reconnect without an issue. It seems to happen in the morning when I come back to the office.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added an few lines to hopefully help pinpoint what my problem is. @YisroelTech, I have checked off the "Use UDP (recommended)" setting and I still had issues connecting to the host pc. It happened again after I restarted my PC.

Comment: Also, did ou check debugging steps on official website? https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/109391-fix-connectivity-issues-partner-did-not-connect-to-router

Comment: @Destroy666, it seems that IPv6 was the culprit. After disabling it and rebooting the Host PC, I was able to connect to it without having to try multiple times.